# Apache 2.2 ignoring VirtualDocumentRoot VirtualHosts?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, apache, httpd.conf

I have several domains that I would like to have wildcard subdomains enabled for through mod_vhost_alias

Included in my httpd.conf I have the following generalized rules:

```
<VirtualHost [ip here]:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user1/public_html
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost [ip here]:80>
    ServerName *.domain1.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/user1/subdomains/%-3+
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost [ip here]:80>
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user2/public_html
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost [ip here]:80>
    ServerName *.domain2.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/user2/subdomains/%-3+
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that apache is completely ignoring the virtualhosts with the wildcard ServerNames. Any request for test.domain1.com or test.domain2.com will just show the contents of /home/user1/public_html (the default rule according to apache).

### Some other information:

`/home/user1/subdomains/test` and `/home/user2/subdomains/test` both exist and have files in them

All my domains have a wildcard subdomain listed in bind config, and they are pointing to the same IP specified in the Vhost rules. Standard Vhost rules for subdomains work, but not wildcard.

A snipped version of the output of `httpd -S`

```
# httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
[ip here]:80      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server domain1.com (/etc/httpd/sites/user1:1)
         port 80 namevhost domain1.com (/etc/httpd/sites/user1:1)
         port 80 namevhost *.domain1.com (/etc/httpd/sites/user1:14)
         port 80 namevhost domain2.com (/etc/httpd/sites/user2:1)
         port 80 namevhost *.domain2.com (/etc/httpd/sites/user2:14)
Syntax OK
```

```
# httpd -M
Loaded Modules:
 core_module (static)
 mpm_prefork_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 include_module (shared)
 log_config_module (shared)
 logio_module (shared)
 mime_magic_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 vhost_alias_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 suexec_module (shared)
 php5_module (shared)
 suphp_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Any suggestions as to what the problem is would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm such a noob, it was a real simple solution.

`ServerName` does not allow wildcards, but `ServerAlias` does, so I just duplicated the servername again.

Here is the final minimized config for domains anyone who happens to find this answer (I hate it when you search on google and find questions but no answers):

```
<VirtualHost [ip here]:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user1/public_html
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost [ip here]:80>
    ServerName domain1.com #<-- The fix. Wildcards not supported in ServerName
    ServerAlias *.domain1.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/user1/subdomains/%-3+
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you use wildcards in the VirtualDocumentRoot?

Comment: Well, this is a super late reply from my inactiveness and chances are you wont see it, but maybe others will. *Yes*, that's what the %-3+ does, it takes everything starting at the 3rd part (seperated by dots) from the right and everything preceding it. For `http://subsub.sub.domain1.com` it would use `/home/user1/subdomains/subsub.sub/` for it's documentroot.

Comment: @Kyle and Mike actually no *wildcards* (the "***"), just its [specific parameters](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#examples) that work more like a `substr`. Also I believe `VirtualDocumentRoot` is actually meant to be used outside `<VirtualHost>`, tho we can limit it by using it inside.

Answer (score 0):

David, this solution that stops mod_rewrite cycle when success will be useful for your problem).

Rewrite round-robin stopper:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200|[45]0[0-9]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```