# Apache Virtual Host by directory

Tags: apache

(Newbie to Apache terminology)

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 with Apache.  Is it possible to direct any www request to a subdirectory off DocumentRoot?  Example, say I have /production.  As I create new sub directories, such as "/production/blog.com", I would like any *.blog.com requests to pull from that directory.  Is there a way to wildcard the Apache configuration in some way?

Comment: the `ServerAlias` directive allows wildcards, so you could have `ServerAlias *.example.com` to let that particular host/vhost definition handle ALL example.com hostnames. With some appropriate mod_rewrite magic, you could transformer the wildcarded hostname part into a subdirectory reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, like this:  http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html

Comment: @user962019 - [Simple dynamic virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html#simple).  I don't believe mode_rewrite is required for this, though it is for some of the later examples.

Comment: Thanks.  How do you control which URL is allowed in "%0" of "VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%0/docs"?  My goal is to allow anything - e.g., *.blog.com (www.blog.com, site.blog.com, download.blog.com, ...etc)

Comment: Per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#interpol, `%0` will match the entire host name, and should be exactly what you're looking for.  I'd also review the rest of this page for some helpful examples.

Comment: Is it possible to define a default website for requests that do not exist?

Comment: @user962019 - Specify a `VirtualHost` with a `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` directive for this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/785966/apache-2-2-ignoring-virtualdocumentroot-virtualhosts has a good example of this.