# VirtualHosts not working (Mod_proxy, Proxmox)

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, mod-proxy

For starters I use Proxmox to virtualize several machines.
Now I want my main machine to redirect the traffic accordingly based on the servername.
I had the setup working once, but now somehow it won't work.

my default host:

**00_proxmox_domain_com.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName proxmox.domain.com
ServerName *.proxmox.domain.com
#RewriteLog "/root/rewrite.log"
#RewriteLogLevel 10
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nrd/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/javascript/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vncterm/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.*\.js$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login.pl$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^proxmox\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I have several similar virtualhost, (currently only this one is activated)
This should send the visitor to PHPMyAdmin on virtual server with IP 192.168.1.13

**02_pma_domain_com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName pma.domain.com
ServerName *.pma.domain.com

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.13/
ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.13/
</VirtualHost>
```

And there is the Proxmox virtual hostfile

**pve.conf**

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
StartServers 2
MinSpareServers 1 
MaxSpareServers 2
MaxClients          50
MaxRequestsPerChild 30
</IfModule>

  ServerName localhost
  ServerSignature Off
  ServerTokens Prod
  ServerAdmin root
  AddDefaultCharset On

  # Hint: Ajax use KeepAlive, which in effect disables MaxRequestsPerChild,
  # so we need to disable KeepAlive to prevent exhaustive memory usage, or
  # at least make sure that periodic updaters interval > KeepAliveTimeout 
  KeepAlive Off

  DocumentRoot /usr/share/pve-manager/root
  <Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
  </Directory>

  <Directory /usr/share/pve-manager/root>
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

  LogLevel warn

  # do not log access to our ajax services
  SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/ws/" dontlog

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined env=!dontlog 

  Alias /images/  /usr/share/pve-manager/images/
  Alias /css/ /usr/share/pve-manager/css/
  Alias /javascript/ /usr/share/javascript/
  Alias /vncterm/ /usr/share/vncterm/

  # avoid authentication when accessing favicon
  Alias /favicon.ico /usr/share/pve-manager/images/favicon.ico

  PerlModule Embperl
  EMBPERL_SESSION_ARGS "config=DB_File Lock=Semaphore"

  AddType text/html .epl

  PerlRequire /usr/share/pve-manager/root/startup.pl

  PerlSetVar PVESatisfy any     
  PerlSetVar PVEPath /  
  PerlSetVar PVELoginScript /login.pl

  PerlTransHandler PVE::URLRewrite

  Alias /nrd/ /__no_real_dir__/

  <Directory "/usr/share/pve-manager/root">
  AuthType PVE::AuthCookieHandler
  AuthName PVE
  PerlSetVar PVECookieName PVEAuthCookie
  #PerlSetVar AuthCookieDebug 5

  PerlAuthenHandler PVE::AuthCookieHandler->authenticate
  PerlAuthzHandler PVE::AuthCookieHandler->authorize

  require group root

  DirectoryIndex index.htm index.pl

  <FilesMatch ".*\.htm$">
EMBPERL_APPNAME PVE
    EMBPERL_SYNTAX EmbperlBlocks
    EMBPERL_OBJECT_BASE base.epl
EMBPERL_INPUT_ESCMODE 0
EMBPERL_ESCMODE 0
    SetHandler  perl-script
    PerlHandler Embperl::Object
    Options     ExecCGI
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch ".*\.epl$">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny From all
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch ".*\.pl$">
    SetHandler perl-script
PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
    Options +ExecCGI
  </FilesMatch>

</Directory>

<Location /nrd/LOGIN>
  AuthType PVE::AuthCookieHandler
  AuthName PVE
  PerlSetVar PVECookieName PVEAuthCookie
  #PerlSetVar AuthCookieDebug 5
  SetHandler perl-script
  PerlHandler PVE::AuthCookieHandler->login
</Location>

<Location /ws/>
  SetHandler perl-script
  PerlHandler $PVE::HTMLServices::Obj->handler
</Location>

<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pve/pve-ssl.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pve/pve-ssl.key

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

</VirtualHost>
```

If you see an obvious error, please tell me.

If you have a working install of proxmox it would help if you could give me your pve.conf
And if you've got the virtualhosts working one of those files would be most welcome.

I've tried several things to solve the problem, without any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, thanks to:
[Apache 2.2 ignoring VirtualDocumentRoot VirtualHosts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785966/apache-2-2-ignoring-virtualdocumentroot-virtualhosts)

There should be only one ServerName, and it can't contain any wildcards,
you should use ServerAlias instead ;)